# Stylesheet doesn't work in firefox and IE

Tags: stylesheet

I'm loosing it right now because I have no idea why my stylesheet won't load in another browser than chrome !
This is the link to my page that need styling : http://peda.au-fil-du-temps.com/toutes-nos-offres/

Maybe I haven't seen something obvious, but I've tried and tried and tried... I don't get it.
Can one of you guys help me out with this ?
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your sources are not linked correctly.

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://peda.au-fil-du-temps.com/js/fitrify.min.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://peda.au-fil-du-temps.com/js/fitrify.css
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://peda.au-fil-du-temps.com/wp-content/themes/divi_theme_enfant/libel-webfont.ttf
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://peda.au-fil-du-temps.com/wp-content/themes/divi_theme_enfant/libel-webfont.svg#libel_suitregular
Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type text/html:

etc....

hit F12 to open the dev console and investigate your url paths.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply ! Ghhh I don't get it ! Because even when I give it the absolute path  it doesn't recognize it ! ... This is driving me mad right now. And if the path wasn't good, why would it work in chrome ? Look I'll change the paths, and you can check by yourself.

Comment: Check that you actually have the files in the right place.  It may also be a permissions issue (folders should be chmod 755, files 644 on most standard apache type set ups), although that would likely give a 403, not a 404.  It probably works in Chrome because it's cached from a time when it did work.  The fix may be as simple as adjusting a leading `/` character to make the link reference root vs  the faked folder (mod rewrite pretty url)

Comment: Thak you so much for your help but I can't get anywhere, this is the first time it's happening to me... I've changed the paths, tried all the syntax I could... changed my chmods... But even when I empty the chrome cache, it's still working.. And yes all my files are in the right place. This is so weird..

Comment: The paths seem alright now, I'm not getting any errors anymore but the stylesheet is still not working !!! It's crazy. Because even when it was saying to me that I had path errors, some of the styling was working : like the "read more" pink button ! And the javascript was working too. I just don't understand why it's calling some of the styling and not all of it like it does in chrome..

Comment: I can't be of any more help... my office filter is blocking some elements on your site which renders it incomplete.  the paths do look correct now.